# Show text over videos for specific time

Tags: video-editing

Easiest way to add Overlay Text over Videos (avi,mp4 etc)?

So far I have tried **MS PowerPoint 2010** to add text over video but i don't see any options to show text for specific time. Plus the output format is WMV and it takes ages to get output from the powerpoint.

**Avidemux** doesn't seem to have Text options. It has logo option which is good.

Any other software which is easy to use and flexible to work with different fonts family,size sizes and custom time duration?

For ex.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html) is great and very easy to use with lots of different effects possible. For more options have a look at [VideoStudio](http://www.corel.com/corel/product/index.jsp?pid=prod4900075) (from Corel).

Comment: Camtasia looks great. It's easy to add text and sync with other.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any Video Editor

- [Windows Movie Maker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/get-movie-maker-download)
- [ezvid](http://www.ezvid.com/)
- [AVS Video Editor](http://www.avs4you.com/AVS-Video-Editor.aspx)
- [Adobe Premiere Pro](http://www.adobe.com/in/products/premiere.html%E2%80%8E) and [Adobe After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/in/products/aftereffects.html%E2%80%8E) (Professional)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Movie Maker is no longer working, you can use [freemake](http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/) for this aim. try the subtitle option, it lets add texts onto video at any time you want. you'll need to create a subtitles file (look [here](http://help.elucidat.com/editing-pages/video-and-audio/subtitles) , then just add this file as decribed [here](http://www.freemake.com/how_to/how_to_add_subtitles_to_a_movie)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please include the instructions directly in your answer from the sites you linked in case they go down. Also, Welcome to Super User. Please read [How to Recommend Software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) then [edit] your answer to include at least the minimum required information (the items in **bold**). Posts without this information may be subject to deletion. Thanks for contributing.